# OpenCV 4.0.1 link failure in Android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, linker

I am migrating the OpenCV library from 3.2.0 to 4.0.1. In the process discovered that lot of macros have been redefined to more C++ style like CV_BGR2RGB is now COLOR_BGR2RGB.

Currently faced with following link errors when trying to link ../native/libs/x86_64/libopencv_java4.so as follows

```
native/jni/include\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:548: error: undefined reference to 'cv::error(int, std::string const&, char const*, char const*, int)'

native/jni/include\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:561: error: undefined reference to 'cv::error(int, std::string const&, char const*, char const*, int)'

xxx_std.h:355: error: undefined reference to 'cv::putText(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, std::string const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, double, cv::Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)'

LabelUtils.cpp:1225: error: undefined reference to 'cv::putText(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, std::string const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, double, cv::Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)'

LabelUtils.cpp:2512: error: undefined reference to 'cv::imwrite(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'

TrackingCodeDeSkew.cpp:553: error: undefined reference to 'cv::putText(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, std::string const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, double, cv::Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)'

TrackingCodeDeSkew.cpp:557: error: undefined reference to 'cv::putText(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, std::string const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, double, cv::Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)'
```

This is the linker command line

```
    C:\Users\koush\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=x86_64-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/koush/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/koush/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem C:/Users/koush/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/x86_64-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat
<<list of generated object files>> -llog OpenCV401/native/libs/x86_64/libopencv_java4.so src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/libzbarjni.so src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/libiconv.so -landroid -latomic -lm "C:/Users/koush/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86_64/libsupc++.a" "C:/Users/koush/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86_64
/libgnustl_shared.so"
```

Comment: Due to lack of time, I have upgraded to 3.4.5 which retains the distribution format similar to OpenCV 3.2.0. No errors were reported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you consider switching back to OpenCV 3.x anytime, you will need backward compatibility header like this:

```
/*
 * OpenCV 4.0.1 backward compatibility header.
 * */

#ifndef ANDROID_DOXCAPTUREUI_OPENCV4_COMPAT_H
#define ANDROID_DOXCAPTUREUI_OPENCV4_COMPAT_H

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <cmath>

#if CV_MAJOR_VERSION > 3

// namespace cv;
//{
#ifndef CV_TERMCRIT_ITER
#define CV_TERMCRIT_ITER cv::TermCriteria::MAX_ITER
#endif

#ifndef CV_BGR2GRAY
#define CV_BGR2GRAY cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY
#endif

#ifndef CV_BGR2RGB
#define CV_BGR2RGB cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB
#endif

#ifndef CV_RGB2GRAY
#define CV_RGB2GRAY cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY
#endif

#ifndef CV_BGRA2GRAY
#define CV_BGRA2GRAY cv::COLOR_BGRA2GRAY
#endif

#ifndef CV_GRAY2RGBA
#define CV_GRAY2RGBA cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGBA
#endif

#ifndef CV_GRAY2RGB
#define CV_GRAY2RGB cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGB
#endif

#ifndef CV_GRAY2BGRA
#define CV_GRAY2BGRA cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGRA
#endif

#ifndef CV_GRAY2BGR565
#define CV_GRAY2BGR565 cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR565
#endif

#ifndef CV_RGBA2BGR565
#define CV_RGBA2BGR565 cv::COLOR_RGBA2BGR565
#endif

#ifndef CV_RGBA2RGB
#define CV_RGBA2RGB cv::COLOR_RGBA2RGB
#endif

#ifndef CV_RGB2RGBA
#define CV_RGB2RGBA cv::COLOR_RGB2RGBA
#endif

#ifndef CV_RGB2BGR565
#define CV_RGB2BGR565 cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR565
#endif

#ifndef CV_RGBA2BGR
#define CV_RGBA2BGR cv::COLOR_RGBA2BGR
#endif

#ifndef CV_RGBA2GRAY
#define CV_RGBA2GRAY cv::COLOR_RGBA2GRAY
#endif

#ifndef CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C
#define CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C
#endif

#ifndef CV_THRESH_BINARY
#define CV_THRESH_BINARY cv::THRESH_BINARY
#endif

#ifndef CV_BGR2HSV
#define CV_BGR2HSV cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV
#endif

#ifndef CV_BGR2Lab
#define CV_BGR2Lab cv::COLOR_BGR2Lab
#endif

#ifndef CV_RGB2HSV
#define CV_RGB2HSV cv::COLOR_RGB2HSV
#endif

#ifndef CV_HSV2RGB
#define CV_HSV2RGB cv::COLOR_HSV2RGB
#endif

#ifndef CV_THRESH_OTSU
#define CV_THRESH_OTSU cv::THRESH_OTSU
#endif


#ifndef CV_THRESH_BINARY
#define CV_THRESH_BINARY THRESH_BINARY
#endif

#ifndef CV_MOP_CLOSE
#define CV_MOP_CLOSE cv::MORPH_CLOSE
#endif

#ifndef CV_RETR_CCOMP
#define CV_RETR_CCOMP cv::RETR_CCOMP
#endif

#ifndef CV_RETR_LIST
#define CV_RETR_LIST cv::RETR_LIST
#endif

#ifndef CV_RETR_TREE
#define CV_RETR_TREE cv::RETR_TREE
#endif

#ifndef CV_RETR_FLOODFILL
#define CV_RETR_FLOODFILL cv::RETR_FLOODFILL
#endif

#ifndef CV_RETR_EXTERNAL
#define CV_RETR_EXTERNAL cv::RETR_EXTERNAL
#endif

#ifndef CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
#define CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
#endif

#ifndef CV_CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS
#define CV_CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS cv::CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS
#endif

#ifndef CV_FILLED
#define CV_FILLED cv::FILLED
#endif


#ifndef CV_REDUCE_SUM
#define CV_REDUCE_SUM cv::REDUCE_SUM
#endif

#ifndef CV_StsBadArg
#define CV_StsBadArg cv::Error::StsBadArg
#endif
//}

#ifndef cvFastArctan
#define cvFastArctan( Y, X )  ( std::atan2( (Y), (X) ) )
#endif

#endif //endif CV_MAJOR_VERSION

#endif //ANDROID_DOXCAPTUREUI_OPENCV4_COMPAT_H
```

Android NDK is [switched](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Android-NDK-r16) to LLVM's libc++ since the NDK r16 version. With the new major release 4.0, OpenCV is also switched from GNU's libstdc++ to libc++. If you set "-DANDRID_STL=gnustl_shared", it will not work beacuse the default OpenCV binaries are built with the libc++ instead of gnustl. You should set cmake argument "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared" in your build.gradle file like the following:

```
    externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
               //sample cpp flag parameters
                cppFlags "-std=c++14 -Ofast -Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize -fsave-optimization-record -fdiagnostics-show-hotness"
           //sample abi filter parameters
                abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    //set -DANDROID_STL to c++_shared
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared" 
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Yashin Thanks for your response, will give it a try once I get back to it.
One question though - Why should I be defining the macros? Has the approach changed in 4.x for these methods?

Comment: Some macro names are changed with OpenCV 4.x (for instance CV_BGR2HSV --> COLOR_BGR2GRAY). If you have a code base written with OpenCV 3.x, then some macros used in your code base will give an error. Also, the header that I append to my answer is a kind of hack and I think there should be better way to support backward compatibility other than defining macros.

Comment: Glad to share that have been using OpenCV 4.2.0 for sometime now. There was no need for extraneous macros to be defined. Used the new naming style like COLOR_BGR2GRAY as outlined by @Yasin-Yildirim